# Where do I end a PHP session so that a variable, created in the first PHP file, can be used in the second file?

Tags: php, session

I have a website where the user starts on one page and then moves to a second page. The first page initializes and adds values to a counting variable, which I then want to be able to be displayed on the second page. I know to use a session, but I am wondering how I should properly end the session--do I end it on the first page, or the second page? Do both pages need to begin with `session_start()`?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Both must use session start. The variable you are talking about is basically termed cookies. The variables will be shared throughout the browser sessions.